# How do I remove a plugin using webpack-chain?

Tags: webpack, webpack-chain

If I have a resolved Webpack config like this:

```
  ...
  plugins: [
    /* config.plugin('vue-loader') */
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    /* config.plugin('define') */
    new DefinePlugin(
      {
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: '"development"',
          BASE_URL: '"/"'
        }
      }
    ),
    /* config.plugin('case-sensitive-paths') */
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
```

How do I remove the `DefinePlugin` using [`webpack-chain`](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
config.plugins.delete("define");
```

Comment: I get this , config.plugins.delete is not a function